# Unfortunately App has been crashed when using android phone to launch the app

Tags: java, android, xml

In logcat cause is mentioned like this

```
10-21 19:23:51.751 20211-20211/? E/Zygote: v2
```

10-21 19:23:51.751 20211-20211/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
10-21 19:23:53.771 20211-20211/com.example.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 20211
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
at com.example.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
at com.example.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
at com.example.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 386564108 byte allocation with 4182480 free bytes and 126MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2230)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3935)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
at android.view.View.(View.java:4226)
at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:591)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:249)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:245)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:241)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
at com.example.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

error is here

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

what's the error?

***here is main.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bk99"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="253dp"
        android:layout_height="263dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="77dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="77dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="411dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/log" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="99dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="99dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="333dp"
        android:background="#1E5F9F"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/user_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="@string/enter_your_name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="217dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="97dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="97dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="262dp"
        android:background="#1E5F9F"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="308dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="141dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/reg"
        android:layout_width="151dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="132dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="132dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        android:background="#1E5F9F"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/remember_me"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, upload your activity_main xml here. thre probably an error in the xml : Binary XML file line #2

Comment: You look like you only uploaded half the stack trace.  When you see this error it almost is always caused by a secondary exception that will be printed immediately below it.  It's always the bottom most one that's the real issue.

Comment: I've uploaded the full stack trace and xml file.

Answer (score 0):

As stated from your log `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 386564108 byte allocation with 4182480 free bytes and 126MB until OOM` your app maybe crashing because your image size too large. I suggest **try compressing your image file or use image loding libraries like  [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)**.